# ".count" doesn't work inside spring jpa-named-queries.properties file in pageable query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-batch

I'm working with Spring Batch and I have to externalize queries my project is using due to requirements. I have encountered the following issue involving a count query inside a JPA Repository using pagination:

```
Hibernate: select * from ( SELECT DISTINCT column1 AS RID, column2 AS TYPE FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'X' AND TRIM(column3) IN (?, ?, ?) order by RID asc ) where rownum <= ?
Hibernate: select count(DISTINCT WHERE) FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'X' AND TRIM(column3) IN (?, ?, ?)
2020-04-20 09:45:43,464 ERROR: o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper [main] ORA-00936: missing expression
```

As you can see, the count query that has been formed, doesn't make sense.

The jpa-named-queries.properties file (\src\main\resources\META-INF) contains the following:

```
Operation.getItems=SELECT DISTINCT column1 AS RID, column2 AS TYPE FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'X' AND TRIM(column3) IN :list
Operation.getItems.count
```

And the repository definition looks like:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemsRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, String> {

    @Query(
            name = "Operation.getItems",
            nativeQuery = true
            )
    public Page<MyClass> findAllItems(@Param("list") List<String> myList, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I've got the same error if I use "countName" inside @Query anotation:

jpa-named-queries.properties (notice distinct in B instead DISTINCT):

```
Operation.getItems=SELECT DISTINCT column1 AS RID, column2 AS TYPE FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'X' AND TRIM(column3) IN :list
Operation.getItemsB=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT distinct column1 AS RID, column2 AS TYPE FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'X' AND TRIM(column3) IN :list)
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemsRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, String> {

    @Query(
            name = "Operation.getItems",
            nativeQuery = true,
            countName = "Operation.getItemsB"
            )
    public Page<MyClass> findAllItems(@Param("list") List<String> myList, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Error:

```
Hibernate: select count(distinct WHERE) FROM mytable WHERE TYPE = 'X' AND TRIM(COLUMN3) IN (?, ?, ?)
2020-04-20 10:36:39,936 ERROR: o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper [main] ORA-00936: missing expression
```

It works fine if I write the count query inside the repository file, but it isn't the objective.

Any idea of what it is happenning?

Thank and regards.

Comment: Same error here, but in my case with Postgresql: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM". It seems that JPA totally ignores the countName field and tries to create the count transforming the Named Query.